# Why is the internal keyword used in this example from Jon Skeet's book?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, access-modifiers

I've been trying to understand the `internal` keyword and when I need to use it. Fortunately, today, as I'm reading in Jon Skeet's book *C# In Depth, 3rd Edition* about how to implement iterators, on p.161-162 there is a use for `internal`:

**Listing 6.32**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class IterationSample : IEnumerable
{
    object[] values;
    int startingPoint;

    public IterationSample(object[] values, int startingPoint)
    {
        this.values = values;
        this.startingPoint = startingPoint;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Listing 6.3**

```
class IterationSampleIterator : IEnumerator
{
    IterationSample parent;
    int position;

    internal IterationSampleIterator(IterationSample parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        position = -1;
    }

    public bool MoveNxt()
    {
        if (position != parent.values.Length)
        {
            position++'
        }
        return position < parent.values.Length;
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get 
        {
            if (position == -1 ||
                position == parent.values.Length)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            int index = position + parent.startingPoint;
            index = index % parent.values.Length;
            return parent.values[index];
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }
}
```

So why `internal IterationSampleIterator`? As I understand, `internal` is usually in place of `public`; so help me understand why `public IterationSampleIterator` could cause problems that are solved by replacing `public` with `internal`.

Comment: I think you should ask yourself the opposite question. Why would you use `public` there if `internal` is sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before going any deeper in the posted code, you may review the [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173121.aspx) on access modifiers in .Net C#.

Idea remains we make something internal when we want that to be accessed only within the `assembly (mostly dll)`. It may seem similar to `public`, but usage is quite different, since for `public` its an open access for all the callers from anywhere.

In the code sample the usage of internal has a different perspective, this is more to control the object of the `IterationSampleIterator` class, by making the constructor `internal`, so this class can only be instantiated from the callers within its own assembly, but any other caller from outside cannot do it.

For all the users outside the assembly they can only call the methods like property like `Current` or Methods like `MoveNext` and `Reset` to work with internal implementation there's no direct access to the object.

Normally such would be the case where within assembly there are certain classes which internally use and thus expose the wrapped functionality. I think `System.IO` is one of the assemblies exposing such classes, with can be used within the assembly boundaries

Answer (score 2):

It's not about *"`public` could cause problems that are solved by replacing `public` with `internal`"*. It's not about solving problems. It's about the design of your project(s) or library.

If you use the `internal` modifier for a class (or its members), then that class (or members) will only be accessible in the same assembly, and not from other assemblies.

Let's say you're designing a dll library and you have a class that you want to use in other class of your dll, but you don't want to expose this class to the user of your dll. If you use `public`, then the users will be able to see and use the class. But if you use `internal` then the users will not be able to see or use the class, but all your other classes can still use it.

Comment: But what is a reason why you wouldn't want to expose this class to users of your dll?

Comment: There could be million reasons. Have you filled out some government forms that had a section titled something like *"for internal use"* or *"to be completed by officer"*? Wouldn't it be nice if they could simply hide those sections so you cannot see them, but only the officers can? I bet they would love to do so. Well, while that's not practically possible on physical papers, it is possible in software by using the `internal` qualifier. Does this make any more sense now?